# How to calculate Webserver Bandwidth usage

Tags: windows, iis-7, web-server

I have a production web server (VPS) running Server 2008 with II7 and i have been asked to look into the usage of each site (there is about 10 sites running on this server)

I have been looking at a http://niknak.org/software/IIsTrafficMonitor but it seems to only work for IIS6 (unless i have installed it incorrectly, but it worked on the IIS6 server i was trying)

Our Web host has this info only at a global level (ie. totals for the server)

So im after an application where i can compare usage between websites both input and output. I dont mind if its a paid solution or not just as long as it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), it's Open Source and can run on Windows

As this one and many others (webtrends...), it will depends on what you log in IIS. You will need to log the Sent & receive bytes. You should alos log the referer, user agents as good info.

If you didn't include these info, you won't get data for the past, so activate these as soon as possible

Comment: +1 for awstats.  take a bit of fiddling with the log to get it right, but works a like a dream

Comment: I do have IIS logging and i have downloaded the awstats package but im a bit lost installing it. How do i install this on a windows server?

Answer (score 0):

If your web host cannot provide your specific site's log files then you're limited in your options.  First, see if they can provide the log files to you, in which case you can use awstats, SmarterStats, LogParser or similar programs.

If they cannot, then you will need a client-side logging solution like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).  That's a great solution though, even if you have access to the log files.  It just means that you need to add a small bit of data to each of the pages that you will be tracking.

Comment: I can and have setup Logging in IIS (i have full RDP access) and i have enabled the "bytes sent" and "bytes recieved" fields in the logs.

Comment: That gives you full flexibility then.  Some people still prefer Google Analytics, even if you have the logs.  They do a great job of reporting.  Otherwise SmarterStats is my personal favorite, and LogParser when you need to manually dig into the logs.

Comment: We have google analytics already, but im more after the bandwidth usage of the sites in IIS. I'll have a look at SmarterStats then.